# skipWhile in LINQ is not working as excepted

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to learn LINQ and found out from MSD documentation that `SkipWhile` will tend to skip the value as long as the statement is true. however when I use this statement below I am not getting the result as expected.

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };
var allButFirst3Numbers = numbers.SkipWhile(x => x > 9);

foreach (var n in allButFirst3Numbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(n);
}
```

From the code above the result should be

> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

But I am getting the result as

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15

Can anyone point out what exactly am I doing wrong in this, and how to get the expected result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the docs for [Enumerable.SkipWhile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549075(v=vs.110).aspx) (emphasis mine):

> This method tests each element of source by using predicate and skips the element if the result is true. **After the predicate function returns false for an element, that element and the remaining elements in source are yielded and there are no more invocations of predicate.**

So because the first element yields a `false` it will return everything. I suspect what you really wanted to write was:

```
var result = numbers.Where(x => x <= 9);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, i understood it now. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting what you should get.  You are saying skip while x > 9.  1 is less than 9 so it starts taking right away.

Try `.SkipWhile(x=>x<=9)` ... But that will give you 10,11,12,13,...

You may also try `.TakeWhile(x=>x<=9)` which will return 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Answer (score 0):

The said predicate `x => x > 9` will be match in the starting of the list and once that predicate is `false` it will go ahead and consider all the elements. You should rather try to use `Where()` extension method like

```
var allButFirst3Numbers = numbers.Where(x => x > 9);
```

Answer (score 0):

then you want to take, not skip

```
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 15);
var result = numbers.TakeWhile(x => x <= 9);
Debug.Print(string.Join(", ", result)); // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

Comment: It doesn't return the expected result either. It returns till the condition is true, but as soon as the condition is false it does not bother about the remaining items in the list.